# Haxe projects only shows blank Flash Player

Tags: flash, haxe, haxeflixel

I'm getting started using Haxe.  After going through all of the setting up, I should be all ready to go, but when I run any project it opens a Flash Player with a blank screen.  No preloader, not text, just a screen of whatever color is specified in the Project.xml.

I've spent the day looking for a solution but no luck yet.

- I've double checked to make sure everything is up-to-date.
- I have run the project from multiple IDEs and command line.
- I have tried running my own projects, demos, HelloWorld, etc.
- Other Flash projects run fine. I'm only having this problem with Haxe projects.

Everything produces the same result: A blank Flash Player.

Having spent this much time looking for a solution, I'm almost positive it has to be something extremely stupid that I'm overlooking.

Here's the Project.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<app title="HelloWorld" file="HelloWorld" main="Main" version="0.0.1" company="HaxeFlixel" />

<!--The flixel preloader is not accurate in Chrome. You can use it regularly if you embed the swf into a html file
<!--or you can set the actual size of your file manually at "FlxPreloaderBase-onUpdate-bytesTotal"!-->
<app preloader="flixel.system.FlxPreloader" />

<!--Minimum without FLX_NO_GAMEPAD: 11.8, without FLX_NO_NATIVE_CURSOR: 11.2 -->
<set name="SWF_VERSION" value="11.8" />

<!--------------------------------WINDOW SETTINGS------------------------------->

<!--These window settings apply to all targets-->
<window width="640" height="480" fps="60" background="#000000" hardware="true" vsync="true" />

<!--Web-specific-->
<window if="web" orientation="portrait"  />

<!--Desktop-specific-->
<window if="desktop" orientation="landscape" fullscreen="false" resizable="true" />

<!--Mobile-specific-->
<window if="mobile" orientation="landscape" fullscreen="true" width="0" height="0" />

<!--------------------------------PATHS SETTINGS-------------------------------->

<set name="BUILD_DIR" value="export" />
<classpath name="source" />
<assets path="assets" />

<!--------------------------------LIBRARIES------------------------------------->

<haxelib name="flixel"/>

<!--In case you want to use the addons package-->
<!--haxelib name="flixel-addons" /-->

<!--In case you want to use the ui package-->
<!--haxelib name="flixel-ui"/-->

<!--In case you want to use nape with flixel-->
<!--haxelib name="nape" /-->

<!--------------------------------HAXEDEFINES----------------------------------->

<!--Enable the Flixel core recording system-->
<!--haxedef name="FLX_RECORD" /-->

<!--Disable the right and middle mouse buttons-->
<!--haxedef name="FLX_NO_MOUSE_ADVANCED" /-->

<!--Disable the Native cursor api for Flash target-->
<!--haxedef name="FLX_NO_NATIVE_CURSOR" /-->

<!--Optimise inputs, be careful you will get null errors if you don't use conditionals in your game-->
<!--haxedef name="FLX_NO_MOUSE" if="mobile" /-->
<!--haxedef name="FLX_NO_KEYBOARD" if="mobile" /-->
<!--haxedef name="FLX_NO_TOUCH" if="desktop" /-->
<!--haxedef name="FLX_NO_GAMEPAD" /-->

<!--Disable the Flixel core sound tray-->
<!--haxedef name="FLX_NO_SOUND_TRAY" /-->

<!--Disable the Flixel sound management code-->
<!--haxedef name="FLX_NO_SOUND_SYSTEM" /-->

<!--Disable the Flixel core focus lost screen-->
<!--haxedef name="FLX_NO_FOCUS_LOST_SCREEN" /-->

<!--Disable the Flixel core debugger. Automatically gets set whenever you compile in release mode!-->
<haxedef name="FLX_NO_DEBUG" unless="debug" />

<!--Enable this for Nape release builds for a serious peformance improvement-->
<haxedef name="NAPE_RELEASE_BUILD" unless="debug" />

<!--------------------------------CUSTOM---------------------------------------->

<!--Place custom nodes like icons here (higher priority to override the HaxeFlixel icon)-->
```

**FIX:**
Windows had a different default player for .swf files.  I changed this to the correct version and everything works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of things causing this:

1. FlashDevelop using the incorrect Flash player.
2. FlashDevelop's invocation of the Flash player passes a "/c" command-line argument that the Flash Player Projector stand-alone player doesn't like.

Here's how to make it work:

1. Download the Flash Player Projector content debugger from https://www.adobe.com/support/flashplayer/downloads.html.  Be sure to get the **debugger** version.  It can be a little confusing; at the time I downloaded, it was the link that says "for Netscape-compatible browsers" even though it's a stand-alone executable.  The file I downloaded is called **flashplayer_14_sa_debug.exe**.  Put this file in a handy location.
2. In the same place where you stored the debug player, create a new batch file called **play.bat** and make its contents as shown below.  Put in the correct Flash Player Projector executable name if yours differs from **flashplayer_14_sa_debug.exe** (the part after `%~dp0`):

   ```
   @"%~dp0flashplayer_14_sa_debug.exe" "%2"
   ```
3. In FlashDevelop, we'll now tell it to use **play.bat** as its Flash player.  From the *Tools* menu, select *Program settings...*, then select the *FlashViewer* item under *Plugins*.  On the right side of the pane, click in the path area of *External Player Path* and then click the ellipses (...) button to browse for a player.  Find the **play.bat** file you created in the step above, then click the *Open* button.  Then *Close* the dialog box.

[image: FlashViewer settings page]

You should now be able to play and debug from FlashDevelop.  The key is the use of **play.bat** to take out the "/c" option that FlashDevelop tries to pass to the Flash Player, which is what causes the blank screen.

Comment: Fantastic instructions, but sadly it is still opening Flash Player 10

Comment: @user3717754 You set the External Player Path to point to the "play.bat" file?  And then, what happens if you rename "play.bat" to "foo.bat"?  And what version of FlashDevelop are you using?

Comment: Yes, I set it to play.bat.  If I rename it foo.bat and restart the program, the field is empty in the settings.  If I build and run anyway, it opens Flash Player 10.

I am using FlashDevelop 4.6.2.5

Comment: When the Flash Player 10 is up, open the Task Manager, go to the Processes tab, and see if you can find the entry for the Flash Player.  If you find it, right-click on it and choose "Properties."  You should then be able to see the path of the Flash Player executable (adjacent to "Location").  It'd be interesting to know where this Flash Player lives, maybe there's a clue there, but it could be even more interest to rename or move that executable...  :-)

Comment: C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Adobe Flash CS4\Players.
The executable is FlashPlayer.exe.

Comment: FIXED! It was Windows' fault all along!  Flash Player 10 was the default program to open .swf files.  I changed that the correct player, and everything works fine.  Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are using FlashDevelop.

Can you post the contents of your Project.xml and any .hxml build files you have?

> You probably want to use your own compile.hxml file, as this will
>   allow you to use more compilation options. In order to achieve this go
>   to project -> properties -> enable "no output". This will completely
>   disable compilation. Then just go to build -> pre-build command line
>   and insert "path\to\haxe\haxe.exe" "path\tohxml\compile.hxml". Click
>   OK. Whenever you compile, test or run, FlashDevelop will use your hxml
>   file. You can even edit your hxml file within FlashDevelop.

Comment: Added the Project.xml to the OP.
You're correct about me using FlashDevelop.

Answer (score 0):

A blank Flash player windows might happen if you are using the normal and old version of Flash Player and not the debugger version. If there is any exception you won't see it.

Check your Flash Player version and make sure you are using the debugger version too. It has to be 11.8+ so it can support gamepads, native cursors, etc.

Check [this page](http://www.adobe.com/support/flashplayer/downloads.html) for the latest one and make sure you are downloading the *Projector content debugger* one for your OS

Comment: This may be close to the solution.  My Flash Player is up to date, but when I try to run my Haxe projects, it's opening Flash Player 10.